# Do Chinese people have an Internet equivalent of typing everything in all caps?

Tags: internet-slang

I recently realized that since Chinese characters have no uppercase equvalents, it's impossible to create a simple equivalent of "Internet scream" by typping everything uppercase. Are there any techniques specific to Chinese Internet communities that achieve a similar goal?

Comment: use very large text or all bold

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no uppercase or lowercase in Chinese, we can only use very large text to 'yell' with text

For example, use 36pt characters for specific words in a text that's typed in 12pt

- 平常語氣 (normal speech)
- **嚴肅口吻** (serious/ stern tone)
- [image: 大聲呼喊](yell loudly)

Comment: How about [咆哮体](https://www.douban.com/group/topic/18187457/)?

Answer (score 3):

I AM VERY ANGRY!

我很生气！！！
(Add a lot of "!" at the end of the sentence. This can be seen in some publications such as novels.)

我！很！生！气！  I! AM! VERY! ANGRY!
(Insert a "!" between each character. This is very informal, and it is usually used in chatting software. Also, it is stronger.)

Answer (score 2):

Simply add "!!!" to end of your sentences.